# Global в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть две функции

```
def back_phone():
    global l,e,iplabel
    vvod = e.get()
    req = requests.get('https://'+vvod)
    b = bs(req.text,'lxml')
    result = b.find(class_='number-item').text
    need = result[170:270]
    need1 = re.sub('                          ','',need)
    l = Label(w, text=need1, font=('Corbel', 10, 'bold', 'roman'))
    l.place_forget()
    l.place(x=5,y=40)
    e.delete(0,END)

def front_phone():
    global l,e,iplabel
    l.place_forget()
    numcountry = Label(w, text='+7')
    numcountry.place(x=0, y=0)
    e = Entry(w, width=20)
    e.place(x=20, y=0)
    b = Button(w, text='Проверить', command=back_phone, fg='red', bg='black', activeforeground='white',activebackground='blue', bd=4)
    b.place(x=145, y=0)
    e.delete(0,END)
```

Мне надо, чтобы функция front_phone видела переменную l и удалила виджет с ней. Но получается name error

Comment: А почему вы не хотите передать переменную как аргумент и вернуть её в функции?

Comment: Считается, что использование global не очень хороший тон. Лучше передавать аргументы.

Comment: А как вы запускаете эти функции и в каком порядке? Может они у вас в разных потоках вообще работают. Или `front_phone` первой запускается.

Answer (score 1):

При первом входе в функцию `front_phone` до первого вызова `back_phone` (который вызовется только после нажатия на кнопку, которая создается в функции `front_phone`) переменная `l` еще не инициализирована никаким значением, поэтому получаете ошибку `NameError: name 'l' is not defined`. Можно инициализировать эту переменную значением `None`, и делать `place_forget` только если там не `None`:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def back_phone():
    global l  # Объявлять глобальными нужно только те переменные, которые функция изменяет
    # vvod = e.get()
    # req = requests.get('https://'+vvod)
    # b = bs(req.text,'lxml')
    # result = b.find(class_='number-item').text
    # need = result[170:270]
    # need1 = re.sub('                          ','',need)
    need1 = str(random.randint(0, 9999))
    l = Label(w, text=need1, font=('Corbel', 10, 'bold', 'roman'))
    l.place_forget()
    l.place(x=5,y=40)
    e.delete(0,END)


def front_phone():
    global e
    
    if l:
        l.place_forget()
    
    numcountry = Label(w, text='+7')
    numcountry.place(x=0, y=0)
    e = Entry(w, width=20)
    e.place(x=20, y=0)
    b = Button(w, text='Проверить', command=back_phone, fg='red', bg='black', activeforeground='white',activebackground='blue', bd=4)
    b.place(x=145, y=0)
    e.delete(0,END)  # Не понятно, зачем очищать текстовое поле, если оно только что создано


w = Tk()

l = None
front_phone()

w.mainloop()
```

Вообще не понятно зачем эти манипуляции с созданием-скрытием метки, если можно создать метку один раз, а потом просто менять ее текст:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def back_phone():
    # vvod = e.get()
    # req = requests.get('https://'+vvod)
    # b = bs(req.text,'lxml')
    # result = b.find(class_='number-item').text
    # need = result[170:270]
    # need1 = re.sub('                          ','',need)
    need1 = str(random.randint(0, 9999))
    l['text'] = need1
    e.delete(0,END)


def front_phone():
    global e, l
    numcountry = Label(w, text='+7')
    numcountry.place(x=0, y=0)
    e = Entry(w, width=20)
    e.place(x=20, y=0)
    
    l = Label(w, font=('Corbel', 10, 'bold', 'roman'))
    l.place(x=5,y=40)
    
    b = Button(w, text='Проверить', command=back_phone, fg='red', bg='black', activeforeground='white',activebackground='blue', bd=4)
    b.place(x=145, y=0)


w = Tk()

front_phone()

w.mainloop()
```